# In an MVC model, where is the position of http handlers?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tornado

I'm developing Python tornado apps in MVC. I have a folder for models which contains all of classes to access database. another for controller which contains classes to do some controls an more logical works. the problem is that I don't know exactly where to put my HTTP handlers. should I put them in View folder of controller? if not, what should I put in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can take example from Django, which use model named MTV (Model-Template-View) - you can read more about this [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html#the-mtv-or-mvc-development-pattern) or in [FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names). In this model request handlers are placed inside view section, which can be thought as controllers of standard MVC (and templates of MTV are views of MVC - it's a bit confusing).

Comment: I think controller is not like handlers, I use handlers only to renders pages and dealing with query strings. Is there any standard model that I can separate my handlers from controllers with?